# Same Domain link is loading in top iFrame and not on whole page

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

We have a header on our main website (Site #1) that is then fed to another website (Site #2). The header has a "My Account" link that is supposed to belong to site #2. When you click on from site #1 it loads full page same window correctly. When you go to site #2 and click the button it loads ONLY in the iframe at the top of the page (essentially the same area that is holding the header).

- Site #1 is www.saclibrary.org
- Site #2 is www.saclibrarycatalog.org

The original link that is supposed to be there for the my account link is https://find.saclibrarycatalog.org/iii/encore/myaccount

To get it to work for now I had to change the link to a redirect page on the first site, then have that page auto-redirect back to the second site's my account page. The urls in the iframe work correctly for any link that is not the same domain (saclibrarycatalog.org). That's why my work around works, but the original link in the same domain does not.

I've found a lot of places online telling you how to make a link load only in the iframe and not in full same page, but not the other way around, and I can't seem to reverse engineer any of those tips. Another web developer I talked to said it was a browser issue, but we have not done any updates to the browsers on the computers here. We are running firefox 25.0.1, and IE 9.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you use modern jQuery for this task?

Answer (score 0):

You should really modernize your method. Using php, asp or cgi (depending on your hosting server capability) will allow you to split your header from the rest of your page (as for the footer and any other part). So loading your page and checking the requested URI, you can decide what is shown, when, and even don't load certain parts of your page.